# Delete SFX file (and parts) after extraction

Tags: command-line, batch-file, winrar

I need to create a SFX file (that is too large, so I need to make at least 5 parts) and I need to delete the SFX and its parts right after the extraction.

I found out in another topic that setting Default64.SFX for the SFX module in the Advanced SFX options dialog in Module tab and adding the line: "%comspec%" /c del "%sfxname%" in the Setup tab can be used to delete an only SFX file after extraction, but it doesn't work for its parts.

Does somebody know how to change this line to delete all the parts of the SFX?
Or maybe another way?

Answer (score 0):

There can be configured in the *WinRAR* window **Advanced SFX options** on tab **Setup** as *Setup program* to *Run after extraction* the *Windows Command Processor* `cmd.exe` referenced with `%ComSpec%` or with `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` with the following argument strings:

```
%ComSpec% /D /Q /E:ON /V:OFF /C for %I in ("%sfxname%") do for %J in ("%~nI") do del /A /F /Q "%~dpI%~nJ.part*.*"
```

There is executed after the extraction of the archive file `C:\Temp\Development & Test(!) 100%\Program Install.part1.exe` with Windows installed to `C:\Windows`:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /D /Q /E:ON /V:OFF /C for %I in ("C:\Temp\Development & Test(!) 100%\Program Install.part1.exe") do for %J in ("%~nI") do del /A /F /Q "%~dpI%~nJ.part*.*"
```

The [Windows commands](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) **DIR** and **FOR** are internal commands of `cmd.exe`.

Please open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `cmd /?` and read the output usage help. It explains the `cmd` options `/D`, `/Q`, `/E:ON`, `/V:OFF`, `/C` (must be the last `cmd` option) and how all the other argument strings after last `cmd` option `/C` are interpreted by the *Windows Command Processor*.

Next run in the command prompt window `for /?` and read also the output usage help.

The fully qualified file name of the executed *WinRAR* self-extracting archive is assigned to the environment variable `sfxname` by the *WinRAR* SFX module as documented in help of *WinRAR* on page with title **SFX commands: Setup**.

The first **FOR** command is just for assigning this string to the loop variable `I` which is for the example above `C:\Temp\Development & Test(!) 100%\Program Install.part1.exe`.

The second **FOR** command processes just the file name string referenced with `%~nI` which is the string between the last backslash (Windows directory separator) and the last dot which is interpreted as beginning of the file extension. This is the string `Program Install.part1` for the example above.

Run in the command prompt window `del /?` for the output of the short usage help of command **DEL** explaining the used options which are:

- `/A` to override the default `/A-H` to match all files independent on their attributes instead of ignoring hidden files as by default to delete the SFX archive files even on having the hidden attribute set (very unlikely);
- `/F` to force the deletion of the SFX archive files even on read-only attribute set (also very unlikely);
- `/Q` to delete the files quietly without prompting the user for confirmation (important).

The used references of the two loop variables `I` and `J` with the modifiers are:

- `%~dpI` referencing the drive and path of the executed SFX file name ending always with a backslash which is for the example `C:\Temp\Development & Test(!) 100%\`.
- `%~nJ` referencing the string from the beginning of the SFX main archive file name `Program Install.part1` already without file extension `.exe` because of `%~nI` up to last character before the last dot which is for the example `Program Install`.

So for the example above is executed finally after the extraction:

```
del /A /F /Q "C:\Temp\Development & Test(!) 100%\Program Install.part*.*"
```

That command deletes now the executed SFX archive file `Program Install.part1.exe` as well as all other parts with file extension `.rar`.